# Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric - - WHY?

Tags: r

I have been on this for  hours and I cannot not detect where the error arises.
[image: this is an example of the data that I enter]

Comment: you have to show entire code, what happened to chch after this line?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For any specific debugging question, it would help if you can provide us the section of code that produce the error, along with the sample input data you use.